# python: access a date field attributes

Tags: python, odoo

I'm using odoo and I created a date field:

```
date = fields.Date(string='Date')
```

I want to enter a date.

My question is: can I access (day - month - year) separately from this given date? and use the accessed data somewhere else? and how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use first

```
d = datetime.strptime(self.date, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

and then you can access the single part of it

```
d.year
d.month
d.day
```

Have a look to [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)